# Struts2 dynamic binding of action class without restart

Tags: struts2

is this possible to load dynamically struts action class without having to restart? I am not using any enterprise application container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/spring-plugin.html

Search the page for "Class Reloading"

Comment: Thanks I am trying this out, it fits my need.

Comment: I just tested it today, that's about a year late :), works well I would like to have control when to reload instead of apache jci. Other options that can be considered are automatic class **HotSwap** using in jvm JRebel or fakereplace (tested)[https://github.com/fakereplace/fakereplace](https://github.com/fakereplace/fakereplace) or [AgentSmith](http://java.net/projects/agentsmith)-new methods/class cannot be added, uses Sun HotSpot VM's feature *Instrumentation.redefineClasses* - These options do not reload struts configurations. Another alternative is  OSGi

Comment: without using the above plugin I find that netbeans 7.1 and greater now redeploys my maven web application on save.  It is fast enough that I can go and view the changes almost instantly, I have found this very helpful.